# Error while trying to run ```corr()``` in python with pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, future-warning

While trying to run the `corr()` method in python using pandas module, I get the following error:

```
FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrame.corr is deprecated. In a future version, it will default to False. Select only valid columns or specify the value of numeric_only to silence this warning.
  print(df.corr())
```

**Note** (Just for clarification) :- `df` is the name of the dataframe read from a `csv`file.

For eg:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
print(df.corr())
```

The problem **only** lies in the `corr()` method which raises the aforementioned error:

```
FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrame.corr is deprecated. In a future version, it will default to False. Select only valid columns or specify the value of numeric_only to silence this warning.
```

I partially understand the error, however I would like to know:

> Are there any other alternative methods to do the same function of `corr()` to identify the relationship between each column in a data set? Like is there a way to replicate the function without using
> `corr()` method?

Sorry If my question is wrong or improper in anyway, I'm open to feedbacks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other reason you want to avoid `corr` method? Because it is not deprecated in general, only the default value of its `numeric_only` argument. Using `df.corr(numeric_only = True)` (or False, depending on the needs) should get rid of the warning.

Comment: Okay thanks...I dont have any other reason for avoiding it other than it throwing errors in my code.

Comment: You should edit the post and add your code to get better help.

Comment: The problem doesn't lie on my code but on that one method - the corr method

Comment: However the comment by @matszwecja solved my problem..i would like to close this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem only lies in the one function `corr()` which is not deprecated
but its `numeric_only` Argument in the function is. So, you can set it to false or true according to needs by `df.corr(numeric_only = *[True/False]*)`.
You can learn more at its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html).

p.s - I wrote so that it is more understandable and the fact that this problem was well known to me.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @matszwecja for the answer,  Using `df.corr(numeric_only = True)` (or False, depending on the needs) should get rid of the warning as,

only the default value of `numeric_only` is deprecated, that is it will be set to false in a future version: [pandas documentation/reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)

P.S:-I wrote this answer to close this question as it has been already answered in comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).