# How do I troubleshoot this ValueError in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am working in Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook. I have confirmed with my professor that the below code works on his machine/notebook but it does not work on mine. I receive a ValueError.

**Step #1**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7WFN.png)plt
import pandas as pd

data = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')
```

**Step #2**

```
#Display the first five rows
data.head()
```

**Step #3**

```
#Use a condensed heatmap to identify correlations for the price column. 
#Sort the results, include annotations that format the values with three decimal places, and remove the color bar.
sns.heatmap(data=data.corr().sort_values(by="price", ascending=False), annot=True, fmt=".3f", cmap="coolwarm", cbar=False)
```

Below is the error I received after the third step:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 3
      1 #Use a condensed heatmap to identify correlations for the price column. 
      2 #Sort the results, include annotations that format the values with three decimal places, and remove the color bar.
----> 3 sns.heatmap(data=data.corr().sort_values(by="price", ascending=False), annot=True, fmt=".3f", cmap="coolwarm", cbar=False)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:10054, in DataFrame.corr(self, method, min_periods, numeric_only)
  10052 cols = data.columns
  10053 idx = cols.copy()
> 10054 mat = data.to_numpy(dtype=float, na_value=np.nan, copy=False)
  10056 if method == "pearson":
  10057     correl = libalgos.nancorr(mat, minp=min_periods)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-pa[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmTOe.png)ckages/pandas/core/frame.py:1838, in DataFrame.to_numpy(self, dtype, copy, na_value)
   1836 if dtype is not None:
   1837     dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
-> 1838 result = self._mgr.as_array(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, na_value=na_value)
   1839 if result.dtype is not dtype:
   1840     result = np.array(result, dtype=dtype, copy=False)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py:1732, in BlockManager.as_array(self, dtype, copy, na_value)
   1730         arr.flags.writeable = False
   1731 else:
-> 1732     arr = self._interleave(dtype=dtype, na_value=na_value)
...
   1346 # we need to ensure __array__ gets all the way to an
   1347 # ndarray.
   1348 return np.asarray(ret)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ideal'
```

Does anyone have any recommendations for steps I can take to troubleshoot?

I ran the code on another machine, my professor's, and they successfully generated the heatmap so I confirmed that the code is not the problem.

I uninstalled Anaconda using [these steps](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and then reinstalled it following [these steps](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/mac-os/). I retried the code and received the same error.

Comment: What were the versions of the involved packages on your instructor's computer verse yours? Minor aside: Always a good check things by running the code you paste here before you consider it done? Right off the bat, code block #1 has issues.

Comment: So when I run your code with Pandas 1.5.1 and Python 3.10, I get a warning but it works. The warning for the heatmap line is, "FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrame.corr is deprecated. In a future version, it will default to False. Select only valid columns or specify the value of numeric_only to silence this warning." That probably explains what has happened. You are probably using a current version and need to specify valid columns or **`numeric_only`**. The 'cut' column is a string and so '`Ideal`' and other strings are causing your issues.

Comment: <continued> If I install Pandas 2.2.0, I see your error, `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ideal'` when I run your code block #3. See more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74398104/8508004) and learn how to investigate what versions you have installed. `%pip list` run in your notebook can be one way of starting to look into this. Or if Anaconda/conda is your package manager then you can use `%conda list` in your notebook. Fix for the line in block 3 is ...

Comment: <continued> `sns.heatmap(data=data.corr(numeric_only=True).sort_values(by="price", ascending=False), annot=True, fmt=".3f", cmap="coolwarm", cbar=False);`. With the addition of `numeric_only=True` for the correlation function, it makes the heatmap. (Extra context: Pandas 2 introduced a lot of improvements to make things more robust and stable going forward as a result often the jumpy from 1.5 to Pandas 2 means you have to tweak things. Usually if you search around with the exact error someone has lead the way! This short of minor adjustment being needed is characteristic of open source.)